# Mathematical functions in Swift

Tags: swift

How do I use mathematical functions like `sqrt()`, `floor()`, `round()`, `sin()`, etc?

---

When doing:

```
_ = floor(2.0)
_ = sqrt(2.0)
```

I get:

> error: use of unresolved identifier 'floor'
>   error: use of unresolved identifier 'sqrt'

[image]

Comment: If you get the `Ambiguous reference to x` check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34357943/1359306

Answer (score 101, accepted):

As other noted you have several options. If you want only mathematical functions. You can import only Darwin.

```
import Darwin
```

If you want mathematical functions and other standard classes and functions. You can import Foundation.

```
import Foundation
```

If you want everything and also classes for user interface, it depends if your playground is for OS X or iOS.

For OS X, you need import Cocoa.

```
import Cocoa
```

For iOS, you need import UIKit.

```
import UIKit
```

You can easily discover your playground platform by opening File Inspector (⌥⌘1).

[image: Playground Settings - Platform]

Comment: In the Swift playground, I get the error: `No such module 'Cocoa'`

Comment: @noilly: kinda late now, you have to set the file type to iOS in the Playground's file properties (Cmd-Opt-0), or import UIKit instead, per above comment

Comment: No such module 'Cocoa'

Comment: UIKit, Cocoa, Foundation, all valid choices.

Comment: Importing Cocoa does not work in iOS applications. The "No such module 'Cocoa' error arrises. If you just import UIKit, you get an error on using sqrt().

Comment: Seems silly to import entire {App,UI}Kit just for math functions. For model classes you shouldn't do this. See @bpresles answer below.

Comment: With linux port of swift, use `import Glibc`.

Comment: Just wondering how we can look up documentation on functions such as "sqrt" in Darwin? Maybe its just me, but I tried and failed to find documentation explaining what functions are available in Darwin and instructions on how to use them. Could someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 78):

To be perfectly precise, Darwin is enough. No need to import the whole Cocoa framework.

```
import Darwin
```

Of course, if you need elements from Cocoa or Foundation or other higher level frameworks, you can import them instead

Comment: And with Swift 3+, you don't need Darwin (or Glibc) for `sqrt`, `floor` and `round` because you may natively use respectively `0.5.squareRoot()`, `Int(0.5)` and `0.5.round()`.

Answer (score 17):

For people using swift [2.2] on Linux i.e. Ubuntu, the import is different!

The correct way to do this is to use Glibc. This is because on OS X and iOS, the basic Unix-like API's are in Darwin but in linux, these are located in Glibc. Importing Foundation won't help you here because it doesn't make the distinction by itself. To do this, you have to explicitly import it yourself:

```
#if os(macOS) || os(iOS)
import Darwin
#elseif os(Linux) || CYGWIN
import Glibc
#endif
```

You can follow the development of the Foundation framework [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Docs/Status.md) to learn more

---

### EDIT: December 26th, 2018

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012511/mathematical-functions-in-swift/34972828#comment92400026_34972828) by [@Cœur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033581/c%C5%93ur), starting from swift 3.0 some math functions are now part of the types themselves. For example, [Double](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double) now has a [squareRoot](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2885715-squareroot) function. Similarly, `ceil`, `floor`, `round`, can all be achieved with [`Double.rounded(FloatingPointRoundingRule) -> Double`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2886735-rounded).

Furthermore, I just downloaded and installed the latest stable version of swift on Ubuntu 18.04, and it looks like `Foundation` framework is all you need to import to have access to the math functions now. I tried finding documentation for this, but nothing came up.

```
➜ swift          
Welcome to Swift version 4.2.1 (swift-4.2.1-RELEASE). Type :help for assistance.
  1> sqrt(9)
error: repl.swift:1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'sqrt'
sqrt(9)
^~~~


  1> import Foundation
  2> sqrt(9)
$R0: Double = 3
  3> floor(9.3)
$R1: Double = 9
  4> ceil(9.3) 
$R2: Double = 10
```

Comment: And with Swift 3+, you don't need Darwin (or Glibc) for `sqrt`, `floor` and `round` because you may natively use respectively `0.5.squareRoot()`, `Int(0.5)` and `0.5.round()`.

Comment: @Cœur, I've been out of touch with swift for a while. Perhaps you can offer this insight in the form of an answer. Thanks

Comment: For `pow` I needed to include `Glibc` for Linux, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can use them right inline:

```
var square = 9.4
var floored = floor(square)
var root = sqrt(floored)

println("Starting with \(square), we rounded down to \(floored), then took the square root to end up with \(root)")
```

Comment: I get the following error: use of unresolved identifier 'sqrt'.

Comment: I think it's expecting me to declare a function called sqrt, but obviously it's not what I want. Thanks

Comment: You need to import UIKit, or Cocoa, or Foundation.

Comment: is there a function where I can give it an array of Ints and then Swift would return me a function of power of 2 (or 1, or 3, or whatever) that best matches it? like I give it: `[1,2,3]` it would return `y = x` or I would give it [1,4,9] it would return `y = x^2` or something just close in that manner of `f(x)`

Comment: It's working for me, but my playground imports UIKit by default. And it works too, importing Foundation or Darwin instead UIKit.

Answer (score 8):

To use the math-functions you have to `import Cocoa`

You can see the other defined mathematical functions in the following way.
Make a Cmd-Click on the function name `sqrt` and you enter the file with all other global math functions and constanst.

A small snippet of the file

```
...
func pow(_: CDouble, _: CDouble) -> CDouble

func sqrtf(_: CFloat) -> CFloat
func sqrt(_: CDouble) -> CDouble

func erff(_: CFloat) -> CFloat
...
var M_LN10: CDouble { get } /* loge(10)       */
var M_PI: CDouble { get } /* pi             */
var M_PI_2: CDouble { get } /* pi/2           */
var M_SQRT2: CDouble { get } /* sqrt(2)        */
...
```

Comment: Well it is a anser to the actual question "How do I use mathematical functions like sqrt(), floor(), round(), sin(), etc?"

Comment: It is not a correct answer. They are not global functions. You have to `import Cocoa` to use them.

Answer (score 4):

For the Swift way of doing things, you can try and make use of the tools available in the Swift Standard Library. These should work on any platform that is able to run Swift.

Instead of `floor()`, `round()` and the rest of the rounding routines you can use `rounded(_:)`:

```
let x = 6.5

// Equivalent to the C 'round' function:
print(x.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero))
// Prints "7.0"

// Equivalent to the C 'trunc' function:
print(x.rounded(.towardZero))
// Prints "6.0"

// Equivalent to the C 'ceil' function:
print(x.rounded(.up))
// Prints "7.0"

// Equivalent to the C 'floor' function:
print(x.rounded(.down))
// Prints "6.0"
```

These are currently available on `Float` and `Double` and it should be easy enough to convert to a `CGFloat` for example.

Instead of `sqrt()` there's the `squareRoot()` method on the FloatingPoint protocol. Again, both `Float` and `Double` conform to the `FloatingPoint` protocol:

```
let x = 4.0
let y = x.squareRoot()
```

For the trigonometric functions, the standard library can't help, so you're best off importing Darwin on the Apple platforms or Glibc on Linux. Fingers-crossed they'll be a neater way in the future.

```
#if os(OSX) || os(iOS)
import Darwin
#elseif os(Linux)
import Glibc
#endif

let x = 1.571
print(sin(x))
// Prints "~1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

For general Swift [packages](https://www.swift.org/packages/) that are designed to be built on any platform, one might consider adding a dependency on the `swift-numerics` [package](https://github.com/apple/swift-numerics).

The [README](https://github.com/apple/swift-numerics/blob/1883189574c7be40112a712d9b2d49ac5b3ac65f/Sources/RealModule/README.md) says:

> The module defines four protocols. The most general is `ElementaryFunctions`, which makes the following functions available:
>
> - Exponential functions: `exp`, `expMinusOne`
> - Logarithmic functions: `log`, `log(onePlus:)`
> - Trigonometric functions: `cos`, `sin`, `tan`
> - Inverse trigonometric functions: `acos`, `asin`, `atan`
> - Hyperbolic functions: `cosh`, `sinh`, `tanh`
> - Inverse hyperbolic functions: `acosh`, `asinh`, `atanh`
> - Power and root functions: `pow`, `sqrt`, `root`
>
> `ElementaryFunctions` refines `AdditiveArithmetic`, and so also provides addition, subtraction, and the `.zero` property.
>
> The `RealFunctions` protocol refines `ElementaryFunctions`, and adds operations that are difficult to define or implement over fields more general than the real numbers:
>
> - `atan2(y:x:)`, which computes `atan(y/x)` with sign chosen by the quadrant of the point `(x,y)` in the Cartesian plane.
> - `hypot`, which computes `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` without intermediate overflow or underflow.
> - `erf` and `erfc`, the [error function][ErrorFunction] and its complement.
> - Exponential functions: `exp2` and `exp10`
> - Logarithmetic functions: `log2` and `log10`
> - Gamma functions: `gamma`, `logGamma`, and `signGamma`, which evaluate the [gamma function][GammaFunction], its logarithm, and its sign.
>
> The protocol that you will use most often is `Real`, which describes a floating-point type equipped with the full set of basic math functions.
> This is a great protocol to use in writing generic code, because it has all the basics that you need to implement most numeric functions.
>
> The fourth protocol is `AlgebraicField`, which `Real` also refines.
> This protocol is a very small refinement of `SignedNumeric`, adding the `/` and `/=` operators and a `reciprocal` property.
> The primary use of this protocol is for writing code that is generic over real and complex types.>

[SE-0246](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0246-mathable.md) says that much of the above will be added to the Swift standard library after compiler improvements are implemented, so that would be the best option in the future.