# Xcode 6 Beta: No such module 'Cocoa'

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to use the standard Cocoa library in a swift file in Xcode 6 Beta. I followed [this instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH2-XID_0) but when I import the library

```
import Cocoa
```

XCode complains with the error

```
No such module 'Cocoa'
```

I also tried with the REPL and I have no problems at all.
I suppose it's a bug, cause I started different projects and only sometimes I get this error. Any suggestions? I'm using Mavericks (10.9.3)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can't `import Cocoa` from an iOS playground or application. Make sure your code is running in a Cocoa playground (select **OS X > Source** in the new file dialog).

Comment: Ok Thanks. And how can I use common functions and constants such as sqrt, M_PI?

Comment: You should be all set once you've imported Cocoa http://stackoverflow.com/q/24012511/1639670

Comment: Ok, but I need to use them in a iOS application, I cannot import Cocoa as you answered, right?

Comment: Use `import UIKit` instead for iOS applications.

Comment: Oh, I discovered that M_PI, sqrt etc are all imported with Foundation, Thanx

Answer (score 124):

Replace

```
import Cocoa
```

With:

```
import UIKit
```

Comment: does anyone know if there's a way to set this to be the default with new files? I have to do this for every file I create.

Comment: @MatthewKnippen - It seems to be a bug in Xcode, it should know you are doing iOS not OS X development.  File a radar (but actually don't since I am getting a lot of rep out of this)

Comment: it turns out that you can specify when you create a new file. When you do, it keeps the new default.

Comment: of course, if you switch between OS X and iOS programming a lot, then this will still be a problem

Answer (score 22):

From your question, it seems that you are trying to add `Cocoa class` into your iOS Application instead of `Cocoa Touch class`. So this is not a bug of Xcode.

Be sure to select template which are under the **iOS** section shown in the following screenshot, as we are choosing it for an iOS Application.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you've already created your Playground, you can switch between iOS and OS X platforms in the "File Inspector" dialog; there's no need to create a new Playground. `import Cocoa` will only work for an OS X Playground.

Go to View > Utilities > Show File Inspector and then it's on the right under "Playground Settings"

Comment: This one is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

you need to get xcode 6.1 (beta) to use Swift with OS X

Answer (score 2):

You can open the Utilities tab (from the top right) and just switch platform from the Playground settings section. If you switch it from iOS  to OS X the problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Framework named Cocoa does not exists

Remove

> import Cocoa

and everything must works from the scratch.

If this does not work for some reason you can import Foundation or UIKit frameworks