# Easiest way to find Square Root in Swift?

Tags: swift, math, square-root

I have been trying to figure out how to programmatically find a square root of a number in Swift. I am looking for the simplest possible way to accomplish with as little code needed. I now this is probably fairly easy to accomplish, but can't figure out a way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mathematical functions in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012511/mathematical-functions-in-swift)

Answer (score 46):

In Swift 3, the `FloatingPoint` protocol appears to have a `squareRoot()` method. Both `Float` and `Double` conform to the `FloatingPoint` protocol. So:

```
let x = 4.0
let y = x.squareRoot()
```

is about as simple as it gets.

The underlying generated code should be a single x86 machine instruction, no jumping to the address of a function and then returning because this translates to an LLVM built-in in the intermediate code. So, this should be *faster* than invoking the C library's `sqrt` function, which really is a function and not just a macro for assembly code.

In Swift 3, you do *not* need to import anything to make this work.

Comment: UIKit sqrt(Double)

Comment: I like this solution because it doesn't require any imports! 

Answer (score 10):

Note that sqrt() will require the import of at least one of:

- UIKit
- Cocoa

  - You can just import Darwin instead of the full Cocoa
- Foundation

Answer (score 6):

First import `import UIKit`

```
let result = sqrt(25) // equals to 5
```

Then your result should be on the "result" variable

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

sqrt function for example `sqrt(4.0)`

Answer (score 1):

this should work for any root, 
2 - ****∞****, but you probably don't care:

```
func root(input: Double, base: Int = 2) -> Double {
    var output = 0.0
    var add = 0.0
    while add < 16.0 {
        while pow(output, base) <= input {
            output += pow(10.0, (-1.0 * add))
        }
        output -= pow(10.0, (-1.0 * add))
        add += 1.0
    }
    return output + 0.0
}
```

Comment: It is highly recommended to not implement functions that are already available in iOS SDK, Check : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2885715-squareroot

Answer (score 0):

```
func sqrt(num:Int)-> Double {
    var x1:Double = (Double(num) * 1.0) / 2; 
    var x2:Double = (x1 + (Double(num) / x1)) / 2; 
    while(abs(x1 - x2) >= 0.0000001){
        x1 = x2; 
        x2 = (x1 + (Double(num) / x1)) / 2;
        }
    return Double(x2);
  }
print(sqrt(num:2))

**output**
1.414


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuLPj.png
```

Comment: Could you please explain why and how it finds the square root?