# Ambiguous reference to member when using ceil or round

Tags: ios, swift, rounding, ceil

I am just trying to use the `ceil` or `round` functions in Swift but am getting a compile time error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'ceil'.

I have already imported the `Foundation` and `UIKit` modules. I have tried to compile it with and without the `import` statements but no luck. Does anyone one have any idea what I am doing wrong?
my code is as follow;

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class LineGraphView: GraphView {
override func setMaxYAxis() {
            self.maxYAxis = ceil(yAxisValue.maxElement())

    }
   }
```

Comment: Please provide the example code where you're trying to do this.

Comment: The more detail you provide the easier it is for people to help you with the answer.

Comment: I have updated the question with sample code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem occurs for something that might seem strange at first, but it's easily resolved.

Put simply, you might think calling `ceil()` rounds a floating-point number up to its nearest integer, but actually it doesn't return an integer at all: if you give it a `Float` it returns a `Float`, and if you give it a `Double` it returns a `Double`.

So, this code works because `c` ends up being a `Double`:

```
let a = 0.5
let c = ceil(a)
```

…whereas this code causes your exact issue because it tries to force a `Double` into an `Int` without a typecast:

```
let a = 0.5
let c: Int = ceil(a)
```

The solution is to convert the return value of `ceil()` to be an integer, like this:

```
let a = 0.5
let c = Int(ceil(a))
```

The same is true of the `round()` function, so you'd need the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the scope of where you call `ceil`, you may need to explicitly call `Darwin`'s `ceil` function (deep in a closure, etc).  Darwin is imported through `Foundation`, which is imported by `UIKit`.

```
let myFloat = 5.9
let myCeil = Darwin.ceil(myFloat) // 6
```

On linux, `Glibc` is used in place of `Darwin` for C-level API access.  You would have to explicitly `import Glibc` and call `Glibc.ceil(myFloat)` instead of using `Darwin`.