# Does swift have natural log function in it?

Tags: swift

I am writing some functions that will solve problems for me and it requires the use of ln (natural log) but I can't seem to find it in swift and I've searched all over the internet but I still can't find the answer. Any help would be appreciated.

`let rate : Double = log(finalAmount / initalAmount) / time
 return rate`

log should be ln.

Comment: The `log()` function in your question *is* the natural log function.

Comment: No, but `Foundation` has it.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini: Actually, on macOS it is part of the system libraries, and imported via `import Darwin`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mathematical functions in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012511/mathematical-functions-in-swift).

Comment: I don't get that @MartinR. Does Swift has it? Even if we run it on the server side or so?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini: Swift can use the system libraries (such as the standard math library). `import Darwin` on Apple platforms or `import Glibc` on Linux. (Foundation also imports Darwin, so if you import Foundation then you already have it.)

Comment: Such functions will be added to Swift. See [SE-0246](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0246-mathable.md)

Answer (score 2):

import `Foundation` and you'll find `log()` is implemented for all the real number types.  As is `log10()` and other specialist log functions.

Comment: as correctly pointed out by @MartinR above, this is for iOS, and for MacOS its in the system libraries.  For other platforms it will depend if they have ported Foundation or implemented an equivalent.

Comment: For iOS it is also in the system libraries (on all Apple platforms).

Comment: it is?  Unless I import Foundation I don't see it?

Comment: `import Darwin` should be sufficient, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012755/1187415 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/34972828/1187415.

Comment: Interesting read.  Thanks.  Do you know if Foundation re-implements the functions (i.e. are they in native Swift, as I believe Foundation now is?) or does it just import Darwen?